# How to DROP a database with '`' at the beginning as adding single backstick cannot be solved

Tags: mysql, database

How to drop **NAMMIK** with backquote for mysql (innodb_version 10.4.18)? It was unintentionally added by  CALL `sys.create_synonym_db;` Note that adding single backstick does not help the problem as the backstick is at the beginning in this case.

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| `NAMMIK`           |
| NAMMIK             |
| mysql              |
| nammik             |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+

 mysql> DROP DATABSE `NAMMIK`;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATABSE `NAMMIK`' at line 1
```

Comment: To escape a backtick you need to double it see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/JglpGTmF)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

````
DROP DATABASE ```NAMMIK```;
````

Comment: mysql> DROP DATABASE ' ` NAMMIK ` ' ; 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ' ` NAMMIK ` ' ' at line 1  (note : spaces were intentionally added here in order to show the symbol)

Comment: i have updated answer, now try

Comment: I considered it as answer. But, what I did was DROP DATABASE three backquotes without space

Comment: `RENAME DATABASE ```NAMMIK``` TO NAMMIK_TEMP;
DROP DATABASE NAMMIK_TEMP;`  you can try with this to renaming then drop it. hope it will works for you.

Comment: Hope you dont mind, I fixed the syntax error in your answer as it has been accepted it should be correct! See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/b4H9ce3P) showing the issue.